# VBA Error with PivotTable: error 1004 range of object _Global failed

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am creating a PivotTable in VBA whose range is first calculated and then a table created from that. However, it's showing an error so can someone please correct it? It's showing:

> error 1004 range of object _Global failed.

```
Sub Pivottable()

    Dim NewRange As Range
    Dim n As Long

    Sheets("DUT1_Test51_excel").Select

    n = Worksheets("DUT1_Test51_excel").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

    Set NewRange = Range("A3" & ":" & "Q" & n)

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=Range(NewRange), _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
        CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="DUT1_Test51_excel!R3C22", _
        TableName:="PivotTable1", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14

    Sheets("DUT1_Test51_excel").Select
    Cells(3, 22).Select

    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField _
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("20431"), "Average of 20431", xlAverage
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("time")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Where does it give you the error?

Comment: IN THE LINE      "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14

Answer (score 0):

try this (changed NewRange to a String) :

```
Sub Pivottable()

    Dim NewRange As String
    Dim n As Long

    Sheets("DUT1_Test51_excel").Select

    n = Worksheets("DUT1_Test51_excel").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

    NewRange = "A3:Q" & n


   ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
   SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
   SourceData:=Range(NewRange), _
   Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
        CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="DUT1_Test51_excel!R3C22", _
        TableName:="PivotTable1", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14

    Sheets("DUT1_Test51_excel").Select
    Cells(3, 22).Select

    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("20431"), "Average of 20431", xlAverage
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("time")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. The above problem is solved but now its showing error "unable to get pivot field property of pivotTable class "   in line  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("20431"), "Average of 20431", xlAverage                .

Comment: Ok, do you have a Column in your data base (the sheet from which you generate the pivot table) named "20431"? But as you call just after `PivotFields("time")`, you may change it to "time" or any other column's header name.

Comment: yes I have a column named 20431 and also a column named time(time is containing all the date with time values)

Comment: A bit strange... got rid if the "_" in the edit, give it a try!